# creating a new dataframe from array of values

Tags: pandas

```
0    {'not_needed': 'not_needed', 'needed': ['', 'PPP', 8.414448]}
1    {'not_needed': 'not_needed', 'needed': ['', 'FFF', 7.414448]}
```

Just learning with pandas and I somehow parsed a complex data like this. But how can we create a new pandas dataframe from the array values of the key `needed` by ignoring the first empty string value and using just the other 2 values in 2 new pandas column named `name` & `value`?

ExpectedOutput(Two columns with numbered index)

```
0    {'name': 'PPP', 'value': 8.414448}
1    {'name': 'FFF', 'value': 7.414448}
```

Comment: Could you add an expected output to your post? It would be easier to understand what should be done.

Comment: @Arkadiusz just updated. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You wrote you wanna see 2 values in 2 new pandas columns, but looking at the input and the output, it seems you have a dataframe with two long strings in one column and you would like to have them converted to other two strings in one column, but with different pattern.

Comment: @Arkadiusz I only needed the values in the key `needed`. Its an array and want to create a new dataframe from that with each item in the array as a new column. As the first item in the array is an empty string I want to ignore that & just use the last 2 values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `Series` has regular schema i.e. all rows have same dict keys, and level of nesting you're touching:

```py
ds1 = ds.str["needed"].str[1:]
ds2 = pd.DataFrame(ds1.to_list(), columns = ["name", "value"])
ds3 = pd.Series(ds2.to_dict("record"))
```

For the input in `pd.Series` format:

```py
import pandas as pd

ds = pd.Series([{'not_needed': 'not_needed', 'needed': ['', 'PPP', 8.414448]},
{'not_needed': 'not_needed', 'needed': ['', 'FFF', 7.414448]}])
```

Now to explain steps:

`ds1` - the way to interact with `list` or `dict` in `pandas` row is by invoking `.str[key]` where `key` can be either `dict` key or `list` reference.

`ds2` - is the way to break `ds1` into columns, with predefined names.

`ds3` - `to_dict("record")` will convert your data frame into list, where each row is represented by single entry of the format `{column1_name: column1_value_rowN, column2_name: column2_value_rowN, ...}`

Comment: This works. Thank you for taking the time to explain this. Just one doubt, Is it possible to ignore the first empty string during creation of the dataframe?

Comment: No worries, that's exactly what `.str[1:]` is doing

Comment: yes indeed. Just figured that out. Thank you.